# How to mock a dependency in Supertest using Jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

I am writing a test case for a route in Node.js using Supertest and Jest. Right now I am testing a login route.

```
router.post(
  '/users/login',
  [phoneNumberValidator],
  validateRequest,
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { phoneNumber } = req.body;

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ phoneNumber });
    const uuid = uuidv4();

    // If existingUser is true
    if (existingUser !== null) {
      const otp = createOtp();

      const tempAuthData: string = JSON.stringify({
        identifier: uuid,
        phoneNumber,
        otp,
      });

      try {
        await new TwilioService().sendOtp('+1111111111', otp);
      } catch {
        throw new ServiceError('Twilio service down');
      }

      try {
        await redisClient.setWithExpiry(uuid, tempAuthData, 65);
      } catch {
        throw new ServiceError('Redis service down');
      }

      res.send({ identifer: uuid });
    } else {
      // We do not want to expose if the phone number is our user
      // Redirect the user to OTP page anyway, but do not send OTP SMS
      res.send({ identifier: uuid });
    }
  }
);

/// Twilio service
class TwilioService {
  private _client: any;

  constructor() {
    const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
    const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
    this._client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
  }

  async sendOtp(targetPhoneNumber: string, message: string) {
    const phonNumber = targetPhoneNumber.replace(/\s/g, '');

    return this._client.messages.create({
      body: message,
      from: process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
      to: phonNumber,
    });
  }
}
```

You can see we have a `await new TwilioService().sendOtp('+1111111111', otp);` that obviously does invoke other services, and I don't want this to happen in my test suite. Therefore I included a `jest.mock` in my test case. I tried the manual mock by creating `__mocks__` folder and automatic mock. It works if I directly create the `TwilioService` object in my test file. The new object is calling my mock `constructor` and my mocked method.

```
jest.mock('../../services/twilio-service');

// This works!!!!!
it('Test mock', () => {
  new TwilioService().sendOtp('', '');
});
```

However, it doesn't work when I am testing it with Supertest.

```
it('returns 200 even if the phone number has never been used', async () => {
  // This request is calling the original TwilioService and made a network call!!!!
  await request(app)
    .post('/auth/users/login')
    .send({ phoneNumber: '+852 67696351' })
    .expect(200);
});
```

Since Supertest is testing the route directly, I don't see a way to do dependency injection. Is there any way I can make sure the mock is used everywhere in my test suites?